# Looking for a PayPal donation plugin similar to JoomDonation

Tags: plugins, paypal

http://joomdonation.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=23&Itemid=12

I'm creating a non-profit website for a very big charity, and I'm <strike>looking</strike> NEEDING a plugin to handle donations via PayPal.

I've been searching for over 2 days, nearly 8 hours straight for a donation plugin that connects to Paypal to get a balance toward a goal, and has a customizable "Goal" image so they can use their own images.

I'd like it to also be able to show the latest donators (Possibly all of them if needed) so they can give credit where it is due. (They sometimes run contests involving the donators, so it would need to keep track of all the donators)

I've tried nearly everything, but the only thing that even comes remotely close is a Joomla extension.

I don't care if I have to have 2-3 different plugins to get it working, but it needs to be automated, so no manual updating of the goals to make it work.

I'm really out of ideas to find anything....

I'm open to Commercial plugins, as long as it has my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, take a look at following plugins, maybe someone could help you:

- [Easy WordPress Donations](http://codecanyon.net/item/easy-wordpress-donations/1861818?ref=straightforward)
- [Awesome Donation System for Wordpress](http://codecanyon.net/item/awesome-donation-system-for-wordpress/153277?ref=straightforward)
- [PayPal Payment Terminal Wordpress](http://codecanyon.net/item/paypal-payment-terminal-wordpress/166082?ref=straightforward)

However all these plugins are commercial, but you can ask a question to the author about your needs before buying. If you need account there you can register [here](http://codecanyon.net/signup?ref=straightforward).

Comment: Hmm!  That "Easy WordPress Donations" plugin seems really close.  Thank you for these suggestions; I hadn't found these through a normal Google search, somehow......

Comment: You are welcome. If you like an answer vote it up and mark as right answer.

Comment: I can't vote up yet (15 rep required), but I'm going to mark it correct.  I bought the plugin this morning.  Thank you!